# making new batch in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

```
batch(
    tensors,
    batch_size,
    num_threads=1,
    capacity=32,
    enqueue_many=False,
    shapes=None,
    dynamic_pad=False,
    allow_smaller_final_batch=False,
    shared_name=None,
    name=None
)
```

can someone please explain each and every term explicitly of this function

Comment: Doesn't look like anything to me.

Comment: Why not refer to tensorflow doc?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting directly from the documentation of [tf.train.batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch):

"Args:

- **`tensors`**: The list or dictionary of tensors to enqueue.
- **`batch_size`**: The new batch size pulled from the queue.
- **`num_threads`**: The number of threads enqueuing `tensors`.  The batching will be nondeterministic if `num_threads > 1`.
- **`capacity`**: An integer. The maximum number of elements in the queue.
- **`enqueue_many`**: Whether each tensor in `tensors` is a single example.
- **`shapes`**: (Optional) The shapes for each example. Defaults to the inferred shapes for `tensors`.
- **`dynamic_pad`**: Boolean.  Allow variable dimensions in input shapes. The given dimensions are padded upon dequeue so that tensors within a batch have the same shapes.
- **`allow_smaller_final_batch`**: (Optional) Boolean. If `True`, allow the final batch to be smaller if there are insufficient items left in the queue.
- **`shared_name`**: (Optional). If set, this queue will be shared under the given name across multiple sessions.
- **`name`**: (Optional) A name for the operations."